# Let $H$ and $N$ be normal subgroups of a group $G$ with $H \cap N = \{e\}$. Prove that $hn = nh$ for all $h \in H$ and $n \in N$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

What does $H \cap N = \{e\}$ imply here? Is it related to the divisibility of the orders of $H$ and $N$? If so, how do I relate that to show commutativity?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: look at the element $(h^{-1}n^{-1}h)n$ and (the same) $h^{-1}(n^{-1}hn)$, where $h \in H$ and $n \in N$. To which subgroup(s) does it belong?

Comment: Thank you for the insight.

Comment: You are welcome! By the way if gcd$(|H|,|N|)=1$, then by Lagrange's theorem $H \cap N=1$. So normal subgroups having a relatively prime order must commute!

Answer (score 2):

Let $h\in H$ and $n\in N$, then we have $n^{-1}hn\in H$ and $hnh^{-1}\in N$. So we get $n^{-1}hnh^{-1}$ is in both $N$ and $H$. As $H\cap N=\{e\}$ we have $n^{-1}hnh^{-1}=e$ so $hn=nh$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is so much cleaner than what I thought it would be.